# How can I produce a plot showing how fast A and B are accumulating?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following array. How can I produce a plot showing how fast A and B are accumulating? There are no options other than "A" or "B".

```
votes = {"B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A"...
```

Not certain if this is the correct approach, but the closest I have gotten is the below, but it errors on the first iteration.

````
 alist := Accumulate[votes]; (*output is {"B", "A" + "B", "A" + 2 "B", "A" + 3 "B", "A" + 4 "B", "A" + 5 "B", 
 "A" + 6 "B", "A" + 7 "B"...}*)

 list := {#[[1]][[1]], #[[2]][[1]]} &[alist]; (* ERRORS  

Part::partd: Part specification B[[1]] is longer than depth of object.*)
```
````

Comment: This is a basic signal processing question in disguise. Determine a sample period, then calculate the difference in votes each period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact output you are hoping for, but here's one way:

```
votes = {"B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B"};
percentB = Accumulate[votes //. {"A" -> 0, "B" -> 1}]/Range[Length[votes]]

{1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 5/6, 6/7, 7/8, 8/9, 4/5, 9/11, 5/6, 10/13, 11/14}
```

The output here can be interpreted as the percent of time "B" has been chosen out of the current number of votes. To get the same for "A", use

```
percentA = 1 - percentB
```

Then plot:

```
ListPlot[{percentA, percentB}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This answer also works!

Answer (score 9):

You may define a function that counts the A and B's and adds the position. "Sow/Reap" is helpful here:

```
votes = {"B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", 
   "A"};

a = b = c = 0;
res = Reap[
   If[# == "A", Sow[{++c, ++a}, 1], Sow[{++c, ++b}, 2]] & /@ votes;][[2]]

ListLinePlot[res, PlotLabels -> {"B", "A"}, AxesLabel -> {"Pos.", "Count"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Accumulate can work on multiple lists simultaneously:

```
ListLinePlot[
  Transpose[
    Accumulate[
      Transpose[votes /. {{"A" -> 1, "B" -> 0}, {"A" -> 0, "B" -> 1}}], 
  PlotLabels -> {"A", "B"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

#### I.

```
tD = Accumulate @
   TemporalData[{#, 1 - #} & @ (votes /. {"A" -> 1, "B" -> 0}), {1},
     MetaInformation -> {"Labels" -> {"A", "B"}}];

ListLinePlot[tD, Mesh -> All, PlotLabels -> tD["Labels"]]
```

[image]

#### II.

```
accumulatedVotes = Thread[{#, Range @ Length @ #}] & /@ PositionIndex[votes];

ListLinePlot[accumulatedVotes, Mesh -> All, PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Using `FoldList`:**

```
votes = {"B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", 
  "A"};

ListLinePlot[
 Transpose@
  FoldList[If[#2 == "A", #1 + {1, 0}, #1 + {0, 1}] &, {0, 0}, votes]
 , PlotLabels -> {"A", "B"}
 , Mesh -> All
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`Accumulate` with `Coefficient`:

```
Transpose[Coefficient[#, {"A", "B"}] & /@ Accumulate[votes]] // 
 ListPlot[#, Joined -> True] &
```

[image]

With labels:

```
With[{lab = {"A", "B"}}, 
 ListPlot[Transpose[Coefficient[#, lab] & /@ Accumulate[votes]], 
  Joined -> True, PlotLabels -> lab]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
votes = {"B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B","A"};
```

From [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/287614/106) (but not efficient):

```
occurrenceSum[x_,lst_List]:=MapIndexed[Count[lst[[;;First@#2]],x]&,lst]

occurrenceSum["A",votes]

(* {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3} *)
```

```
ListLinePlot[occurrenceSum[#,votes]&/@{"A","B"},PlotMarkers->Automatic,
  PlotLabels->{"A","B"}]
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

```
data=Block[{x={0,0}},
    (Scan[If[#=="A", x[[1]]+=1;Sow[x], x[[2]]+=1;Sow[x]]&,votes]//Reap)[[2,1]]
    ]

(* {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 8}, 
    {2, 8}, {2, 9},{2, 10}, {3, 10}} *)
```

Alternatively, using [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) instead of [`Scan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html) (probably faster?)

```
dataalt=Block[{x={0,0}},
  (Do[If[votes[[i]]=="A", x[[1]]+=1;Sow[x], x[[2]]+=1;Sow[x]],{i,Length@votes}]//Reap)[[2,1]]];

data==dataalt
(*True*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
votes = {"B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B"};
a = votes // Map[EqualTo["A"]] // Boole // Accumulate;
b = votes // Map[EqualTo["B"]] // Boole // Accumulate;
ListLinePlot[{a,b}]
```

[image]