# Add the number of occurrences to the list elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm not explaining it well, sorry.

There is a list[j] consisting of randomly selected number {a,b} elements.

For example,({j,4})

```
list[j]={{{2,1},{2,3},{1,2},{1,1}},
         {{3,1},{3,3},{4,2},{4,3}},
         {{1,1},{1,2},{5,2},{5,1}},
         {{4,2},{1,2},{3,3},{5,4}}}
```

I would like to change the above list to display the number of occurrences of {a,b}.

```
list[j] = {{{{2,1},1},{{2,3},1},{{1,2},1},{{1,1},1}},
           {{{3,1},1},{{3,3},1},{{4,2},1},{{4,3},1}},
           {{{1,1},2},{{1,2},2},{{5,2},1},{{5,1},1}},
           {{{4,2},2},{{1,2},3},{{3,3},2},{{5,4},1}}}
```

I break it down further. list[j] consists of the following.

```
list[1]={{2,1},{2,3},{1,2},{1,1}}
list[2]={{3,1},{3,3},{4,2},{4,3}}
list[3]={{1,1},{1,2},{5,2},{5,1}}
list[4]={{4,2},{1,2},{3,3},{5,4}}
```

Since list[1] and list[2] do not have the same combination in {a,b}, each is the first time,so there become

```
list[1] = {{2,1},1},{{2,3},1},{{1,2},1},{{1,1},1}}
list[2] = {{3,1},1},{{3,3},1},{{4,2},1},{{4,3},1}}
```

{1,1} and {1,2} of list[3] are the second time in list[j]

```
 list[3]={{1,1},2},{{1,2},2},{{5,2},1},{{5,1},1}}
```

{4,2} and {3,3} are 2 times, {1,2} the 3 times and {5,4} the 1st time in list[j].

```
 list[4]={{4,2},2},{{1,2},3},{{3,3},2},{{5,4},1}}
```

So the list [j] looks like this.

```
list[j] = {{{{2,1},1},{{2,3},1},{{1,2},1},{{1,1},1}},
           {{{3,1},1},{{3,3},1},{{4,2},1},{{4,3},1}},
           {{{1,1},2},{{1,2},2},{{5,2},1},{{5,1},1}},
           {{{4,2},2},{{1,2},3},{{3,3},2},{{5,4},1}}}
```

What would you suggest I do?

Comment: Thank you, it was a typo.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  The `Tally` **command** is pretty useful and does it **automatically**.

Simply do:

```
list = {{{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}}, {{3, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {4,
      3}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {5, 2}, {5, 1}}, {{4, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 
     3}, {5, 4}}};
flattenList = Flatten[list, 1]
talliedList = Tally[flattenList]
```

That will **output** you a **list of coincidences** next to the element repeated.
You can **create a function** and **call** it over **any list** you may have:

[image]

### **Extra info**

Also I think you are using wrongly the syntax of Wolfram language, as `list[j]` is equivalent of having a function called list and evaluating it at `j`. Then I imagine you are trying to describe a list of lists, so `list[1]` would be `list[[1]]`, to get the first element of the list, `list[[2]]` to get the second list and so on. Rule of thumb: in *Wolfram Mathematica* f[x] <=> in *math* f(x)

This not may completely solve your issue, but you can try adding more information and steps next time.

P.D.
*You may want to detail some of your work in progress to get some help. That can help you to understand the problem better, and being able to simply sharing a simplified version of your trouble will make you a better programmer*

Comment: Nice, but I don't think this is what the OP requires. (A 'running sum' of the occurrences rather than a list of 'coincidences'?). If the list is `{a,b,a}`, then `{{a, 1}, {b, 1}, {a, 2}}` rather than `{{a, 2}, {b, 1}}`?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like we need a sort of "rolling" `Count` that then gets applied in a threaded way.

```
rowRules = FoldList[Merge[{##}, Total] &, Counts /@ list[j]]
```

And then

```
MapThread[
  ReplaceAll[#1, pair : {a_, b_} :> {a, b, {Lookup[#2, Key[pair]]}}] &, 
  {list[j], rowRules}]
```

[I assume there's a typo in your expected output]

Answer (score 5):

For each `j` up to the length of `list`, count occurrences of `{a, b}` elements in `list[j]`, up to and including the elements in `list[j]`. Preserve the order of `{a, b}` elements in `list[j]`.

```
counts = Table[
  SortBy[
    Cases[Tally[Flatten[list[[1;;n]], 1]], {{a_,b_},c_}/; MemberQ[list[[n]],{a,b}]],
    First[#]/.PositionIndex[list[[n]]]&], {n, Length[list]}]
```

> ```
> {
> {{{2,1},1},{{2,3},1},{{1,2},1},{{1,1},1}},
> {{{3,1},1},{{3,3},1},{{4,2},1},{{4,3},1}},
> {{{1,1},2},{{1,2},2},{{5,2},1},{{5,1},1}},
> {{{4,2},2},{{1,2},3},{{3,3},2},{{5,4},1}}}
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that I didn't send a reply.
Your reply was very helpful for me! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[accumulatedCounts]

accumulatedCounts = MapThread[KeyValueMap[List]@*KeyTake] @ 
  {Accumulate[KeyUnion[Counts /@ #, 0 &]], #} &;
```

***Example:***

```
inputlist = {{{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}}, 
             {{3, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}},
             {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {5, 2}, {5, 1}}, 
             {{4, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 4}}};


result = accumulatedCounts @ inputlist
```

> ```
> {{{{2, 1}, 1}, {{2, 3}, 1}, {{1, 2}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1}},  
>  {{{3, 1}, 1}, {{3, 3}, 1}, {{4, 2}, 1}, {{4, 3}, 1}},   
>  {{{1, 1}, 2}, {{1, 2}, 2}, {{5, 2}, 1}, {{5, 1}, 1}},  
>  {{{4, 2}, 2}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{3, 3}, 2}, {{5, 4}, 1}}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Not very efficient, but a solution using [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) to count only to the occurrence of each element in `list`

```
With[{list2=Catenate@list},
  Partition[MapIndexed[{#,Count[list2[[;;#2[[1]]]],#1]}&, list2],4]
] 

(* {
    {{{2, 1}, 1}, {{2, 3}, 1}, {{1, 2}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1}},
    {{{3, 1}, 1}, {{3, 3}, 1}, {{4, 2}, 1}, {{4, 3}, 1}}, 
    {{{1, 1}, 2}, {{1, 2}, 2}, {{5, 2}, 1}, {{5, 1}, 1}}, 
    {{{4, 2}, 2}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{3, 3}, 2}, {{5, 4}, 1}}
   } *)
```

where

```
list={{{2,1},{2,3},{1,2},{1,1}},{{3,1},{3,3},{4,2},{4,3}},{{1,1},{1,2},
      {5,2},{5,1}},{{4,2},{1,2},{3,3},{5,4}}}
```

**Simpler Example**

```
lst={a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,c,d,e,f}

MapIndexed[{#,Count[lst[[;;#2[[1]]]],#1]}&, lst]

(* {{a, 1}, {b, 1}, {a, 2}, {b, 2}, {a, 3}, {b, 3}, {a, 4}, {b, 4}, {c, 1}, 
    {d, 1}, {e, 1}, {f, 1}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list =
  {{{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}},
   {{3, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}},
   {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {5, 2}, {5, 1}},
   {{4, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 4}}};
```

Using `c` as association counter:

```
Module[{c = <|# -> 0 & /@ Union[Join @@ list]|>},
 Map[{#, c[#] += 1} &, list, {2}]]
```

gives

```
{{{{2, 1}, 1}, {{2, 3}, 1}, {{1, 2}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1}},
 {{{3, 1}, 1}, {{3, 3}, 1}, {{4, 2}, 1}, {{4, 3}, 1}},
 {{{1, 1}, 2}, {{1, 2}, 2}, {{5, 2}, 1}, {{5, 1}, 1}},
 {{{4, 2}, 2}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{3, 3}, 2}, {{5, 4}, 1}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

A minor variation:

**Using `MapIndexed`:**

```
alist = {{{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}}, {{3, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 
     2}, {4, 3}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {5, 2}, {5, 1}}, {{4, 2}, {1, 
     2}, {3, 3}, {5, 4}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 2}, {4, 2}}};
```

---

```
d1 = First@Dimensions@alist

MapIndexed[{#1, Count[flist[[1 ;; (#2 - 1) . {d1, 1} + 1]], #1]} &,    alist, {2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

---

**Using `PositionIndex`:**

Using the same list as before but appending the first row to the end of the list.

```
alist = {{{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}}, {{3, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 
     2}, {4, 3}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {5, 2}, {5, 1}}, {{4, 2}, {1, 
     2}, {3, 3}, {5, 4}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 2}, {4, 2}}};


accCounts[k_List] := Module[{
   d1 = If[VectorQ[k], Length@k, #[[2]] &@Dimensions@k]
   , flist = Flatten[#, 1] &@k
   },
  vpi = Values@PositionIndex[flist];
  rvpi = Range@*Length /@ vpi;
  reps = Sort@Flatten[#, 1] &@
    MapThread[Thread[#1 -> #2] &, {vpi, rvpi}];
  rule = MapAt[{1, 1} + QuotientRemainder[# - 1, d1] &, reps, {All, 1}]
  ;
  If[VectorQ[k],
   MapIndexed[{#1, Sequence @@ (#2 /. reps)} &, clist]
   , MapIndexed[{#1, #2 /. rule} &, k, {2}]
   ]
  ]
```

*Usage:*

```
accCounts[alist]

blist = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 5}};
accCounts[blist]

clist = {4, 5, 7, 4, 1, 2, 1};
accCounts[clist]
```